# Is there a chance if I could put a variable into a select-where statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, variables

I am new to PostgreSQL and i am wondering how to put a variable into the select-where statement so that i could loop the whole progress.
Like the code below I wrote:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    east1 DOUBLE PRECISION:= 827818;
    east2 DOUBLE PRECISION:= 827830;
BEGIN
    COPY (SELECT * from "RawDATA_ALL" 
    WHERE ("EAST" BETWEEN east1 AND east2) AND ("NORTH" BETWEEN 821106 AND 821132)) WHERE east1 = east1 AND east2 = east2
    TO 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\RawData_All\xyz.csv' DELIMITER ',';
END $$;
```

Ultimately I am trying to make the code to loop from 827818 to 827830 for every 2 interval I would generate a csv for that.
Any function that I could use in PostgreSQL for this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so in PL/pgSQL, but you need to use dynamic SQL, since `COPY` doesn't support parameters:

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      E'COPY (SELECT * from "RawDATA_ALL"\n'
       '      WHERE ("EAST" BETWEEN east1 AND east2)\n'
       '        AND ("NORTH" BETWEEN %s AND %s))\n'
       'TO ''C:\Users\User\Desktop\RawData_All\'' %L DELIMITER '',''',
      821106,
      821132,
      'xyz.csv'
   )
);
```

Comment: what i got is "prepared statement "format" does not exist"...

Comment: That is PL/pgSQL code, like you can use in a `DO` statement.